# Return single property from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I try to return a specific property from my array, the terminal say:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined.

I want to search a specific element that valid this `button.id === this.state.currentId` control. So, when it's true I want to return `element.buttonColor` and, in the other method I want that its return 'element.url'. Why the first method: getCurrentBackgroundColor work and the second: getCurrentImage don't work?

```
this.state = {
    currentId: null,
    buttons: [
      {
        id: 0,
        url: "./url1.jpg",
        buttonColor: "#b2d8ca"
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        url: "./url2.jpg",
        buttonColor: "#fef6bb"
      }
    ],
  };

  getCurrentBackgroundColor = () => {
    const currentButton = this.state.buttons.find((button) => {
      return button.id === this.state.currentId;
    });

    return currentButton === undefined ? "" : currentButton.buttonColor;
  };

  getCurrentImage = () => {
    const currentButton = this.state.buttons.find((button) => {
      return button.id === this.state.currentId;
    });

    return currentButton === undefined ? "" : currentButton.url;
  };

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LeftRight
        backColor={this.getCurrentBackgroundColor()}
        image={this.getCurrentImage()}
      />
  </div>
}


//In the LEFTRIGHT class
<div
  id="left"
  style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.backColor }}
  key={this.props.backColor}
>
<img src={this.props.image}/>
</div>
```

Comment: *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"* Nothing in your code is using `url` anywhere. Please show us the code that has the error. (Your `getCurrentBackgroundColor` code is correct.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `url` seems to be a property on the `buttons` items. 
Alberto, where are you setting the `currentId`?

Comment: @suuuriam - Yes, but again, nothing in the code shown *uses* it, so nothing in the code shown will cause the given error.

Comment: Agree, you're right.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrectly.  The error that I see is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'buttonColor' of undefined.

Comment: Array.prototype.find  returns undefined and not null if nothing is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed your current id is not set, you can change 'null' in the return sentence.

```js
this.state = {
  currentId: 0,
  buttons: [
    {
      id: 0,
      url: "./url1.jpg",
      buttonColor: "#b2d8ca"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "./url2.jpg",
      buttonColor: "#fef6bb"
    }
  ],
};

getCurrentBackgroundColor = () => {
  const currentButton = this.state.buttons.find((button) => {
    return button.id === this.state.currentId;
  });
  

  return currentButton === undefined ? "" : currentButton.buttonColor;
};

getCurrentImage = () => {
  const currentButton = this.state.buttons.find((button) => {
    return button.id === this.state.currentId;
  });

  return currentButton === undefined ? "" : currentButton.url;
};

console.log("Background: ", getCurrentBackgroundColor())
console.log("Current Image: ", getCurrentImage())
```

Comment: thanks. This is the code that I wrote before to post my question. It work but the same method don't work when I try to pass the url property. I'll refresh the question to permit you to understand my problem. Sorry for my bad explanation, I'm trying to improve it.

Comment: I reviewed your question. Has the same problem bro, the currentId is set to null. If you set it a value, the method will retrieve the url. I don't know why you put currentId on null.

Comment: You are right. The output of the function is right but the image don't display in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.state = {
  currentId: 1,
  buttons: [{
      id: 0,
      url: "./url1.jpg",
      buttonColor: "#b2d8ca"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      url: "./url2.jpg",
      buttonColor: "#fef6bb"
    }
  ],
};

getCurrentBackgroundColor = () => {
  this.state.buttons.map((button) => {
    if (this.state.currentId === button.id) return console.log(button.buttonColor)
  });
};

getCurrentBackgroundColor()
```

Comment: it won't work cause you need to change  this => return console.log(button.buttonColor)
to  return button.buttonColor

Comment: I have just do it but it don't work. I don't know why.